# Displaying first few words without wrapping word - CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to display post list with title and first sentence or first few word but without wrapping words..

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 100%
```

I found some answers which helped but still not what I want..

Here is an example:

this is what I get:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectu...

this is what I want: 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...

Comment: And where's the code you've tried so far?

Comment: `overflow-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    width: 100%`

Comment: @merko Edit it in your question.

Comment: @merko, please view my answer.

Comment: "This is what I want": Based on what? The number of words, width, etc?